# Ways to make an alien viral plague scientifically hard?

Tags: xenobiology, bio-mechanics, biochemistry

Aside from resorting to a grey goo-ish nanoplague that kills indiscriminately regardless of biochemistry, how might an alien virus, bacteria or other pathogen still be dangerous to humans? Could a disease with incompatible biochemistry still cause damage to the human body if a person is exposed to it, or would the lack of appropriate nutrients make it impossible to breed inside a human host and thus cause any intentional or unintentional harm to it?

Comment: Are we to assume you mean a naturally occurring alien virus rather than one bred by aliens specifically to target human biochemistry?

Comment: Yes. I am not ruling out design in favor of nature (either is fine), but if it is a designer virus, it shouldn't be designed specifically for humans.

Comment: Just how alien are we talking? Are they Carbon-based? Do they use DNA and RNA and proteins? Do they have cells with lipid membranes? If yes to all of those this may be possible but if the aliens use a completely unique biochemistry then it becomes very unlikely.

Answer (score 5):

Simple, they excrete a chemical that kills us. Unintentional. They just have to like our body and it is not far fetched. Lots of water, warm, all they need to is to survive in our bodies to a degree. They could live in weaker places (nasal cavity, ear canal), as long as they deposit their poison, it will be deadly to humans.

Comment: Why would they make a home in the body? How could it find food when surrounded  by incompatible material, and why wouldn’t the body destroy it easily?

Comment: Because they like it wet and warm. Being carbon based bacteria, they thrive with the left overs from our body. They hide where our immune system cannot reach, like nasal cavity.

Comment: @JDługosz I don't think you have to assume they *would* be surrounded by incompatible material. Plenty of parasites accidentally kill the creatures they most love to be with.

Comment: By incompatible I mean the biochemestry of what can be digested and gives nutrition.  That's wny nylon and other synthetics don’t rot.

Answer (score 3):

`how might an alien virus, bacteria or other pathogen still be dangerous to humans?` By producing HCN, Hydrogen Cyanide, (or any number of simple compounds that are deadly to humans) as a byproduct of its natural cycle.

`Could a disease with incompatible biochemistry still cause damage to the human body` Yes.

Few diseases (like probably none) *try* to kill their host. The host is the food supply. If you kill the food supply, you have to find a new food supply. viruses/microbes/etc are just doing what all life does: eat create offspring and multiply. Besides, things that small probably don't have the thought process required to "cause any intentional ... harm".

So, you combine a space mission like NASA's Stardust, a microbe or virus that uses ammonia instead of water, and produces Hydrogen Cyanide as a waste product. Due to the molecular structure of the alien disease, it has an exceptionally easy time binding to human proteins/enzymes.cells in order to get the carbon/nitrogen/whatever it needs to multiply. But I feel like [I already know this story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Andromeda_Strain).

Comment: A virus produces nothing. A virus is just a piece of DNA or RNA with an injection mechanism and a few enzymes to get the cell express that DNA. The cell is what produces the new viruses. Think of the virus as hacker that pwns the cell. So the alien pathogen could not be a virus.

Answer (score 0):

Virus, no. A virus is replicated by human cells, and can only be compatible if evolved on earth *or* artificially made by someone who knows exactly how earth biology works.

Some other pathogens,possible, if not very likely. They'd have to be able to live on something that exists in humans. I guess glucose might be it. Still it would only be a 1 in 8 chance encounter if the alien pathogen thrives on the same stereoisomer of a hexose.